# Setting up a hibernate model using annotations to allow cascaded deletes in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, cascading-deletes

I have two tables, doc_table and code_table in a one to many relationship.   I defined a service to delete entries in the doc_table and what I want is that the corresponding entries in the code_table should be deleted at the same time (a cascaded delete).   Here is the service

```
    public void deleteDoctable(String anumber) throws DataBaseAccessException {
    Session session = null;
    try {
    session = HibernateUtils.beginTransaction("emscribedx");
    Query q = session.createQuery("delete Doc_table  where docnumber = :docnum");
    q.setParameter("docnum", anumber);
    q.executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    }  catch (HibernateException e_) {
        e_.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            HibernateUtils.closeSessions();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            NTEVENT_LOG.error("Problem closing hibernate session!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

When I execute this service, it deletes the entry in the Doc_table but does not cascade the delete to the Code_table.    Below is the annotated model of the Doc_table that I am using.   Note that I annotate the one to many relationship with a cascadeType.All.   But I am still not getting the expected cascaded delete.
Any ideas about what is going on?
    import java.util.List;

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.lucene.Text;

import com.artificialmed.domain.code.model.Code_table;
@Entity
@Table (name="doc_table", catalog="emscribedx")
public class Doc_table {
private Long _id; 
private String _acct;
private String _message;
private String _document;
private String _doctype;
private String _review_date;
private String _createDate;
private int _dummyflag;
private String _reviewer;
private String _ProcedureDocLast;
private String _ProcedureDocFirst;
private String _ProcedureDocMiddle;
private String _ProcedureDate;
private String _ProcedureDocNumber;
private String _Note;
private String _dbcreate_date;
private String _docnumber;
private String _selectedcodes ;
private int _viewed ;
private int _postsubmit ;
private List <Code_table> _code_table;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column (name = "id")
public Long getId() {
    return _id;
}
public void setId(Long id_) {
    _id = id_;
}

@Column (name = "acct")
public String getAcct() {
    return _acct;
}
public void setAcct(String acct_) {
    _acct = acct_;
}

@Column (name = "message")
public String getMessage() {
    return _message;
}
public void setMessage(String message_) {
    _message = message_;
}


@Column (name = "document")
public String getDocument() {
    return _document;
}
public void setDocument(String document_) {
    _document = document_;
}

@Column (name = "doctype")
public String getDoctype() {
    return _doctype;
}
public void setDoctype(String doctype_) {
    _doctype = doctype_;
}

@Column (name = "review_date")
public String getReview_date() {
    return _review_date;
}
public void setReview_date(String reviewDate_) {
    _review_date = reviewDate_;
}

@Column (name = "create_date")
public String getCreateDate() {
    return _createDate;
}
public void setCreateDate(String createDate_) {
    _createDate = createDate_;
}

@Column (name = "dummyflag")
public int getDummyflag() {
    return _dummyflag;
}
public void setDummyflag(int dummyflag_) {
    _dummyflag = dummyflag_;
}

@Column (name = "reviewer")
public String getReviewer() {
    return _reviewer;
}
public void setReviewer(String reviewer_) {
    _reviewer = reviewer_;
}

@Column (name = "ProcedureDocLast")
public String getProcedureDocLast() {
    return _ProcedureDocLast;
}
public void setProcedureDocLast(String procedureDocLast_) {
    _ProcedureDocLast = procedureDocLast_;
}

@Column (name = "ProcedureDocFirst")
public String getProcedureDocFirst() {
    return _ProcedureDocFirst;
}
public void setProcedureDocFirst(String procedureDocFirst_) {
    _ProcedureDocFirst = procedureDocFirst_;
}

@Column (name = "ProcedureDocMiddle")
public String getProcedureDocMiddle() {
    return _ProcedureDocMiddle;
}
public void setProcedureDocMiddle(String procedureDocMiddle_) {
    _ProcedureDocMiddle = procedureDocMiddle_;
}

@Column (name = "ProcedureDate")
public String getProcedureDate() {
    return _ProcedureDate;
}
public void setProcedureDate(String procedureDate_) {
    _ProcedureDate = procedureDate_;
}

@Column (name = "ProcedureDocNumber")
public String getProcedureDocNumber() {
    return _ProcedureDocNumber;
}
public void setProcedureDocNumber(String procedureDocNumber_) {
    _ProcedureDocNumber = procedureDocNumber_;
}

@Column (name = "Note")
public String getNote() {
    return _Note;
}
public void setNote(String note_) {
    _Note = note_;
}

@Column (name = "dbcreate_date")
public String getDbcreate_date() {
    return _dbcreate_date;
}
public void setDbcreate_date(String dbcreateDate_) {
    _dbcreate_date = dbcreateDate_;
}

@Column (name = "docnumber")
public String getDocnumber() {
    return _docnumber;
}
public void setDocnumber(String docnumber_) {
    _docnumber = docnumber_;
}


@Column (name = "selectedcodes")
public String getSelectedcodes() {
    return _selectedcodes;
}
public void setSelectedcodes(String codes_) {
    _selectedcodes = codes_;
}

@Column (name = "viewed")
public int getViewed() {
    return _viewed;
}
public void setViewed(int viewed_) {
    _viewed = viewed_;
}

@Column (name = "postsubmit")
public int getPostsubmit() {
    return _postsubmit;
}
public void setPostsubmit(int postsubmit_) {
    _postsubmit = postsubmit_;
}


@OneToMany (mappedBy = "doc_table", targetEntity = Code_table.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List <Code_table> getCode_table() {
    return _code_table;
}
public void setCode_table(List <Code_table> codeTable_) {
    _code_table = codeTable_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cascades are applied when you invoke the corresponding method on the session. Not when executing DML queries. So, assuming docNumber is the ID of the entity, you simply need

```
Doc_table d = (Doc_table) session.get(Doc_table.class, docNumber);
session.delete(d);
```

Note that you should stick to standard Java naming conventions, and avoid noise in your names. Naming a table XXX_table is useless. Naming an *entity* XXX_table is useless, and confusing, and does not respect the naming conventions. A document entity should be named `Document`.

Answer (score 0):

Transitive persistence doesn't do anything when you make arbitrary changes with queries.  In general unless you're performing bulk operations and have performance concerns, it is best to avoid making changes with queries and use the actual hibernate/jpa API.  It messes with caching, breaks session state, is just generally a recipe for hard to decipher issues down the road.

```
  session = HibernateUtils.beginTransaction("emscribedx");
  Query q = session.createQuery("from Doc_table  where docnumber = :docnum");
  q.setParameter("docnum", anumber);
  List<Doc_table> results = (List<Doc_table>)q.list();
  for (Doc_table result: results) {
    session.delete(result);
  }
  session.getTransaction().commit();
```

yes, this involves an extra query.  Welcome to hibernate!  Pretty APIs and magical abstraction are not free.  If you have the actual ID you can avoid this with `Session#load` to create a lazy proxy without an actual select statement.

Comment: Session.get() will make a select query. Session.load() is the one that doesn't load anything (yeah, good naming!).

Comment: whoops, tx for catching that